# Centralized Jenkinsfile outside of the project's SCM?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am experimenting with Pipeline hoping to transition to this from traditional freestyle projects.  I don't like defining the Jenkinsfile build steps and keeping it in SCM because we like to keep our build process standardized across many microservices and when we want to make changes I don't want to touch a Jenkinsfile in dozens of repos.  I see I can define a Pipeline project that let's me define a Jenkinsfile, but I don't see a way to use this Jenkins file in a Multibranch project.  I also note that each repo or branch just gets skipped right now b/c there is no Jenkinsfile in the SCM.

Is there any way for me to maintain this Jenkinsfile centrally and yet use it in these types of Multibranch projects?

Answer (score 2):

You can utilise jenkins shared libraries -> https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/

Each repo will still need a Jenkinsfile in order to kick off the job for its repo/branch. However should you wish too, you can centralise all of the pipelines (And parameters etc).

How much content remains in the jenkinsfile vs in the shared libraries will be up to you and what works for your teams.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @metalisticpain answer, the use of Shared Libraries is key to DRY (Dont Repeat Yourself).

I differ on whether you need to have a Jenkinsfile on the repo, when you don't want to. You can define a Jenkinsfile on a different repo that the one you are building. For Pipeline Projects, on the 'Pipeline' section of the project configuration, you can specify a SCM different from the one associated to the project.

For Multibranch Projects, keeping the Jenkinsfile outside the repo is more complex. I would suggest you to use a standard Pipeline project, and to include the logic that differentiates the build of branchA from the build of branchB inside your code/shared libraries.

I use a repo for keeping my shared libraries, and all Jenkinsfile for 100+ projects and it works very well. Sadly, I could not find any pipeline to help me with this development and had to code all from scratch.